# Jekyll post behaviour in collections

Tags: yaml, markdown, jekyll

I am working with Jekyll to create a website that display two categories of pages, A and B, each category has multiple entries:

> example.com/categoryA/categoryA_item-1

I tried to approach it using collections but they do not appear to support categories in the YAML Front/Markdown, pages will not be practical and blog forces the user to prepend a date to the start of the file name.

Blog seems the most practical but since it is not a blog post it won't behave as I wish it to. Is there any workaround?

Thanks!